how to use qdrant collection with haystack?
I'm trying to use the Qdrant vector database with the Haystack document store in Python.
I can use Qdrant Python to create and manipulate collections.
But how do I use the collections in Haystack?
How do I connect to a specific collection, write a document in a specific collection, or apply a collection filter for a search?

To use Qdrant with Haystack, you should create a collection and write data using the QdrantDocumentStore. In Haystack, a Document Store is an interface to your database.
For the search task, you should use Qdrant retrievers. In Haystack, Retrievers go through all the documents in a Document Store and select the ones that match the user query.

QdrantEmbeddingRetriever
QdrantSparseEmbeddingRetriever
QdrantHybridRetriever

Other resources:

Qdrant-Haystack integration page
Github issue on using an existing Qdrant collection


I checked the documentation before posting. My issue is with the lack of option in those functions to write in a specific collection, and to retrieve applying a collection filter (or other metadata filters). Any solution to do that ?

Please read https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack-core-integrations/issues/729
You can apply filters as explained in the docs: https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/docs/metadata-filtering

Thank-you, I understand the filtering part now.
